# Model field doesn't get updated on first save

Tags: python, django

I've got this UpdateView I'm using to update my channels:

```
class ChannelUpdate(UpdateView, ProgramContextMixin):
    model = ChannelCategory
    form_class = ChannelForm
    template_name = 'app/templates/channel/form.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ChannelUpdate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('channel_index', args=[self.get_program_id()])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChannelUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'is_new': False,
        })
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        channel = Channel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        channel_codes = ChannelCodes.objects.filter(channel_id=channel.pk)

        if 'is_channel_enabled' in form.changed_data:
            for channel_code in channel_codes:
                channel_code.is_active = channel.is_channel_enabled
                channel_code.save()
        return super(ChannelUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

So when I edit a Channel, I have a checkbox, which changes my bool value for my model field `is_channel_enabled` to either True or False. If I do so, I trigger my if-statement in the `def form_valid` method which then loops through all my channel_codes and sets their bool field `is_active` to the same value as the bool field `is_channel_enabled` from my Channel.

But my problem right now is: Lets say I uncheck the box and after I save my form, the bool still is `True` even though I've unchecked the box and it should be False, but if I then edit my Channel again and check the box, the bool changes to `False`, so that every time I check the box, the exact opposite happens: box checked = False, box unchecked = True.

But this also only happens when I do the update. If I create the channel the default value of True is correct, only when I start editing it, the wrong value gets saved. Does someone know where my problem is? Am I using form_valid wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't you use `form.cleaned_data`, instead of `form.changed_data`, like `form.cleaned_data['is_channel_enabled']`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I looked up how to check changes in a model field and found that `changed_data` is the way to do so, would cleaned_data do the same?

Comment: but `form` is not a model, it is a `Form`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well I gave it a shot, but I'm receiving is the error `argument of type 'bool' is not iterable` :/ I'm pretty new to Django, so sorry if I'm misunderstanding some stuff

Comment: use `if form.cleaned_data['is_channel_enabled']:`.

Comment: Well no error now, but I still have the same problem: unchecked = True, checked = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the latest value.
you can chage the form valid method like below

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # channel = Channel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    channel_codes = ChannelCodes.objects.filter(channel_id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    if 'is_channel_enabled' in form.changed_data:
        for channel_code in channel_codes:
            channel_code.is_active = form.cleaned_data.get('is_channel_enabled')
            channel_code.save()
    return super(ChannelUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

It will work.

Comment: This only returns me the error: `'list' object has no attribute 'get'` at line: 

`channel_code.is_active = form.changed_data.get('is_channel_enabled')`

Comment: @unitas_versus yeah, it's a type issue. `cleaned_data` instead `changed_data`. updated code please check it.

Comment: No more error, but sadly not working. I've logged my values and the following happens:

1. `is channel_enabled` (unchecked) is False |
2. `channel_code.is_active` before submitting is True |
3. `channel_code.is_active` after setting the new value is still True |
4. `is_channel_enabled` after checking the checkbox is now True

Comment: I realise this comment it did above sounds a little confusing: to make a TL;DR: my `channel_code.is_active` always stays `True` no matter what value `channel_enabled` has

Comment: did you checked the input checkbox ? I guess it should return true if you checked the check box in form.

Comment: Yes well the checkbox returns the correct value, the only problem is that the `channel_code.is_active` field just doesn't takes the value from `is_channel_enabled`, it's just True all the time, no matter what

Comment: then you should check `save` method of model `ChannelCodes`

Comment: I am sorry, I'm an idiot :( When I added my logger to the code, I accidentally removed the `save()` method, stupid mistake! Now it works, thanks a lot! :)